# Underscore contains from scratch?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, contains

for practice, I'm studying underscore contains from scratch. There's one part of the code that I cannot articulate or understand.  What does this line do:

"return item === target;"

The code:

```
_.contains = function(collection, target) {

    return _.reduce(collection, function(wasFound, item) { 
      if (wasFound) { 
        return true;
  }
      return item === target;
    }, false);
```

};

Comment: What does "test" === "test", or "test1" === "test2" return in your JS console?

Comment: It returns a boolean value of whether `item` and `target` are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just returns a boolean from the callback to `reduce`. The result of the expression `item === target` is a boolean (i.e., either `true` or `false`). It's a short-hand and (IMO) more-elegant way of doing the following:

```
if(item === target) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The `===` is "strict equals", which means it will not perform any type-coercion. This is why `"2" == 2` will return `true` because `"2"` can be coerced into the number `2` (and vice-versa). But `"2" === 2` will return `false` because it does not perform any type-coercion, and the two arguments are of different types.

The `reduce` function works by iterating over each element in a collection and calculating some sort of value that is also used within each iteration.

During the initial call to the `reduce` function, `wasFound` is set to `false` (notice the `false` passed in to the call to `reduce` after the callback). The first `if` will not be satisfied and so the function will execute the `return` statement. This value that is returned will be the *new* value of `wasFound` in the *next* iteration.

This means that as long as `wasFound` is `false`, we will try to see if the next element matches the one that was passed in. If it is `true`, it means that we have found the element we want and so we can just keep returning `true`.

IMO the function is a little bit inefficient because it doesn't break out early once it has found the element it is looking for, and traverses the entire collection regardless.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (wasFound) { 
    return true;
}
```

You are going through the collection, and it the item has already been found, you return true.

```
return item === target;
```

Otherwise, you return true if the current `item` is equal to the `target` are searching are you, and `false` if it is not.